# GTK4 - how to get coordinates of a moving window

Tags: c, events, gtk

In previous versions of GTK, we added a necessary event mask, attached to a `configure-event`.

```
gtk_widget_add_events(GTK_WIDGET(window), GDK_CONFIGURE);

g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "configure-event",
      G_CALLBACK(configure_callback), NULL);
```

We got the corresponding x,y coordinates from the handler.

```
void configure_callback(GtkWindow *window, 
      GdkEvent *event, gpointer data) {
          
   int x, y;
   x = event->configure.x;
   y = event->configure.y;
   ...
}
```

The closest thing that resembles this is `GtkEventControllerMotion`, but it is
for mouse pointer, not for window move events.

How to do it in GTK4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. This is because not all window managers/compositors provide this information, for privacy and/or technical reasons.

Wayland, for example, does not provide window coordinates, because not every Wayland compositor is even a 2D rectangle - for example, kiosk compositors like [cage](https://github.com/Hjdskes/cage) or [gamescope](https://github.com/Plagman/gamescope), or VR compositors like [wxrd](https://www.collabora.com/news-and-blog/news-and-events/wxrd-a-standalone-wayland-compositor-for-xrdesktop.html).

Because of this, the functionality was removed from GTK4. You will need to use an X11-specific API to get this information, but note that you would need to force your application to use X11 (over XWayland on Wayland compositors)

https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/migrating-3to4.html#adapt-to-gtkwindow-api-changes